# Best Practice to define has many through relationship

Tags: schema, relations

Given the Images. Sometimes I needed to fetch lessons related to a course without joining the topic table.
It is a good way to model the Schema in the diagram at the bottom?
Kindly advice.[image]

Answer (score 3):

So I will make two observations:

1. As Phill W. states, joining is fine.  Sometimes you have to do it and it shouldn't be something you avoid as a matter of course.
2. You do *not* have a normalized database.  You have rows associated to other rows through pointers. You have nothing to maintain uniqueness.  And you are discovering you might actually need to perform more joins to get the answers you need.

Let's get rid of the row pointers (`ids`) and look at how your *data*<sup>1</sup> is structured:

[image: Data model without surrogates]

So you'll notice now that there are actual *keys*.  I cannot insert "Underwater Basket Weaving" into `Course` 1000 times.  However, this might become a little unwieldy with enough data as names tend to be large (in terms of bytes) and as a practical consideration we may want to limit the key size.

To do that we can create a new primary key on each table and the original primary key now becomes an **alternate key**.  HOWEVER, we **do not** discard them and we **do not** replace them with a single key as that would destroy the relationships:

[image: A data model with surrogates, composite keys, and alternate keys]

However, this still leaves something to be desired.  `CourseId`,`TopicId`, and `LessonId` are meaningless.  We still need to query the tables to get a system-generated identifier in order to access the data we need, as no one will know "Advanced Topics in Database Design" is actually `CourseId = 12451853`.

In any business or enterprise, people naturally create shorthand for common things.  Think of postal codes, part numbers, etc.  These are understood to be equivalent to the entity's name **outside of** the context of the database.  When possible, we should use these (or create them) to facilitate two things:

1. We don't need to create *another* alternate key to make sure they are unique.
2. The database can be more directly accessed rather than requiring lookups for meaningless `ids`.
3. The chances of transposition errors (Inserting `(1,3,2)` instead of `(1,2,3)`) are eliminated or greatly reduced.

Something like this is closer to an ideal state:

[image: A data model with composite keys and alternate keys, but no surrogates]

Meaningful keys means less data needs to be read to return the desired results from a given query.  Code is neater, mistakes result in failed inserts, not invalid data.  If I need the lessons for CS101 - Introduction to Keyboards I can just do:

```
SELECT
  CourseCode
 ,TopicShortName
 ,LessonShortName
 ,LessonName
 ,Description
FROM
  Lesson
WHERE
  CourseCode = 'CS101'
```

Which I believe is your desired result.

<sup>1</sup>System-generated values that are generally hidden to the user, are not *data* - it is a pointer or an association.  This isn't to say something that is system generated is never data (think of an invoice or policy number), but they generally need to be exposed outside the database itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Sometimes I needed to fetch lessons related to a course without joining the topic table.

Why?
The Topic table's not *going* anywhere so why not let it do it's job?  Linking Lessons (indirectly) to Courses?

You *don't* have to return any *fields* from the Topics table in your query ...

```
select 
  c.title course_title 
, l.title lession_title 
from courses c 
inner join topics t 
   on c.course_id = t.course_id 
inner join lessions l 
   on t.topic_id = l.topic_id 
order by 1, 2 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what others have said, but if you for whatever reason need to denormalize course_id into lessons and want to prevent update anomalies, you can add a UNIQUE constraint in topics:

```
ALTER TABLE topics ADD CONSTRAINT ... 
    UNIQUE (course_id, topic_id);
```

and then remove your current f.k. between lessons and topics and replace it with:

```
ALTER TABLE lessons ADD CONSTRAINT ...
    FOREIGN KEY (course_id, topic_id)
    REFERENCES topics (course_id, topic_id);
```

This is not a good way to model your data but can be useful if other means cannot meet performance requirements.